# DB relationship (elegant for any ORM)

Tags: mysql, sql, orm

I just seek for an advice, what is the best way to a create nice and elegant relationship (that could be used with ORM methods). The content of the database looks like this:

```
  mysql> describe books;
  +--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
  +--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
  | title  | varchar(45) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
  | author | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
  | cover  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
  +--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

  mysql> describe users;
  +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
  +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
  | username | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
  +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

 mysql> describe users_books;
 +---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
 +---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | user_id | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | book_id | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 +---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+

 mysql> describe comments;   
 +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 | body    | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 | rate    | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 | user_id | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

 mysql> describe books_comments;
 +------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
 +------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | book_id    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | comment_id | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 +------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I don't have any issues with that model, but I think it can be improved. In this way I am fetching the records:

```
select body, rate, users.username,title, author from users
inner join users_books on users.id = users_books.user_id
inner join books on books.id = users_books.book_id
inner join books_comments on users_books.book_id = books_comments.book_id
inner join comments on books_comments.comment_id = comments.id
where users.id = 1 and comments.user_id = 1;
```

While users can have many books, a comment is very specific for a book owned by a specific user. I think that is the point I am not getting it the right way.

Comment: Your current structure suggests that a single comment may be about several books (`book_comments` is a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)). Is this really what you want?

Comment: No. A comment should be in one to one relationship to a book, which belongs to a user.

Comment: @RandomSeed is right to point out that a many to many doesn't sound right, but your response is wrong: comments should be one to many with a book. One to one means that each book could only have one comment (and by extension only one person could comment on each book).

Comment: To do the above, you need to drop the `books_comments` table, and move the `book_id` foreign key to the `comments` table.

Comment: You should also make your foreign keys `NOT NULL`, e.g. `comments.user_id`, since all comments must have a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current structure suggests that a single comment may be about several books (`book_comments` is a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)).

But what you want is:

> a comment is very specific for a book owned by a specific user

A "book owned by a user" is nothing else but an entry in the `users_books` table. Drop `books_comments`. Add to `comments` a foreign key to `users_books`' primary key, i.e. `(user_id, book_id)`.

I would create your `comments` table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    book_id INT NOT NULL,
    -- more fields here
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, book_id)
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id, book_id) REFERENCES users_books (user_id, book_id)
);
```

This structure assumes that a comment may be posted by a user only on a book that she owns (`user_id` would be both the book owner and the comment author).

You can add a second foreign key reference to `user` (e.g. a `author_id`) to allow any user (`author_id`) to post a comment on any book (`book_id`) owned by someone in particular (`user_id`).

Comment: Also, the two FKs in `users_books` should be made primary too. It looks like presently that doesn't have a PK at all.

Comment: I appreciate your answers and comments. It is more clear now, how to proceed. Thank you.